# Spoliation and mortality

Tags: word-usage

There is a select group of adjectives more commonly used in their negated form: 'inclement' and 'disfigured' are two examples. What explains their greater usefulness and longevity when compared to the original, positive, words from which they were derived? Are there any other words of this type you would nominate?

Comment: _Uncouth, unkempt_ and _dishevelled_  are all words for which the 'positive' form no longer exists, though all are derived from the negation of archaic words. I don't consider the words you have used in your heading fall into this category, though.

Comment: Thank you, @Kate Bunting, for the excellent examples. Each has prevailed in usage beyond the long-forgotten word from which it was born, and thus are apposite to the question I posed: _What explains their greater usefulness and longevity when compared to the original, positive, words from which they were derived?_  I am only speculating, but one common characteristic of all these words is that their utility lies in describing a state of affairs that is infelicitous by comparison to human expectations, hence they more closely reflect our experience of life than their perfect counterparts.